# dynamodb updateitem with conditionexpression return whether item updated

Tags: amazon-web-services, go, amazon-dynamodb

I would like to update an item under certain conditions and then I would like to know whether the item was updated when UpdateItem returns.

The documentation seems contradictory to me.

On this page: http://docs.aws.amazon.com/amazondynamodb/latest/APIReference/API_UpdateItem.html in the "Conditional Update" example it says "All of the item's attributes, as they appear after the update, are returned in the response."

On this page: https://godoc.org/github.com/aws/aws-sdk-go/service/dynamodb#UpdateItemOutput it says that Attributes is "A map of attribute values as they appeared before the UpdateItem operation"

I don't really want either of these. What I want is a bool that says whether or not there was an update.

This is where my brain is at now:

```
out, err := db.DynamoDB.UpdateItem(&dynamodb.UpdateItemInput{
    TableName: tableName,
    Key: map[string]*dynamodb.AttributeValue{
        "KeyName": {S: aws.String(keyname)},
    },
    ExpressionAttributeNames: map[string]*string{
        "#lock": aws.String("Lock"),
    },
    ExpressionAttributeValues: map[string]*string{
        ":now":     aws.String(compfmt(time.Now())),
        ":promise": aws.String(compfmt(time.Now().Add(30 * time.Second))),
    },
    ConditionExpression: aws.String("attribute_not_exist(#lock) OR :now > #lock"),
    UpdateExpression:    aws.String("SET #lock = :promise"),
})
```

Comment: You can use `ALL_NEW` or `UPDATED_NEW` to get the new values in Attributes.

Comment: Will the result of `UPDATED_NEW` be empty if there was no update? Or does it return the current value after the operation regardless?

Comment: You'll have to try that yourself, but if the documentation is correct, the Attributes map should be empty in that case.

Comment: Thanks! I can write tests for it so I'll see how it goes and report back.

Comment: For reference I went with `UPDATED_NEW` and it's working as expected, although it turns out if the ConditionExpression fails then an error (ConditionalCheckFailedException) is returned so that's equally usable to determine whether or not there was an update.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

One way to do this is to check the `Code` on the `awserr`

```
import "github.com/aws/aws-sdk-go/aws/awserr"
func Lock()(bool, error) {
    //Create value v
    _, err := db.DynamoDB.UpdateItem(v)
    if err != nil {
         if ae, ok := err.(awserr.RequestFailure); ok && ae.Code() == "ConditionalCheckFailedException" {
             return false, nil
         }
        return false, err
    }
    return true, nil
}
```

Answer (score 2):

There are now constants to compare the errors rather than using the hardcoded string as in other answers:

```
result, err := svc.UpdateItem(input)
if err != nil {
    if aerr, ok := err.(awserr.Error); ok {
        switch aerr.Code() {
        case dynamodb.ErrCodeConditionalCheckFailedException:
            fmt.Println(dynamodb.ErrCodeConditionalCheckFailedException, aerr.Error())
        default:
            fmt.Println(aerr.Error())
        }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Turns out what I wanted to do was check the error to see if it contained the string `ConditionalCheckFailedException`.

```
func Lock() (bool, error) {
  ...
  _, err := db.DynamoDB.UpdateItem(v)
  if err != nil {
    if strings.Contains(err.Error(), "ConditionalCheckFailedException") {
      return false, nil
    }
    return false, err
  }
  return true, nil
}
```